# Efficiency of repeated checks with jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does jQuery cache selector lookups?

I am wondering whether this code

```
if ($("#ItemID").length) {
     doSomethingWith($("#ItemID"));
}
```

will be significantly slower than this code

```
item = $("#ItemID");
if (item.length) {
    doSomethingWith(item);
}
```

What about if you're extracting much more of the DOM e.g., `$("div")` rather than just `$("#ItemID")`?  Same answer?

External references/explanation would be helpful, rather than just opinion.

Comment: Note that `if (item)` will always evaluate as true, because $() returns an object. I suspect you meant `if (item.length)`.

Comment: sorry that's what I meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [jQuery Learning Center](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/#saving-selections), "jQuery doesn't cache elements for you. If you've made a selection that you might need to make again, you should save the selection in a variable rather than making the selection repeatedly."

This is particularly important when your selector is slow by its nature. For example, `$("#foo")` makes a call under the covers to `document.getElementById()` which should be very fast. However, a selector like `$("a[rel$='thinger']")` might be significantly slower on an older browser.

Remember that jQuery supports chaining, so you don't always have to introduce a variable to save the selection, you can just chain sequential calls together. For example, in this code I don't introduce a variable just to save the result of `.find("img")`, rather I chain three calls to prop and one to show.

```
clusterBlock.find("img").prop("src", clusterElt.imageUri)
                        .prop("alt", clusterElt.description)
                        .prop("id", clusterElt.imageId)
                        .show();
```

Finally, remember that a saved selection is not updated as the DOM changes. If I get all elements with class "foo" and save that in a variable, then some other piece of code adds and removes a couple of "foo" elements, then my saved selection will be missing the new elements and contain the references to the removed elements.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
var item = $("#ItemID");
if (item.length) {
doSomethingWith(item);
}
```

will be faster but marginally. doSomethingWith will go to pointer where object is stored.
Turns out [people do cache selectors](http://mikeadamsnc.com/cache-jquery-selectors-for-better-performance/) btw